# What is the correct way to use custom vanilla javascript with in a AMP (ACCELERATED MOBILE PAGES) wesbite

Tags: javascript, html, css, amp-html

Iv have gone through [ACCELERATED MOBILE PAGES PROJECT](https://www.ampproject.org/) examples and documentation. It appeared to me that no JavaScript(inline and or src) is allowed. below is the code snippet. and heres the validation error im getting.

*The attribute 'src' in tag 'amphtml engine v0.js script' is set to the invalid value*

```
function loads_stuff(){
          var $body = document.body,
            $menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('menu-trigger')[0];
          if (typeof $menu_trigger !== 'undefined') {
            $menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
              $body.className = ($body.className == 'menu-active') ? '' : 'menu-active';
            });
          }
    }
window.onload = loads_stuff;
```

I understand AMP only lets you uses `<script type="application/ld+json">` as a inline JavaScript, but this is for json. All i really need is to make a very  simple mobile menu with one click event that shows and hides a div.

Comment: Pretty sure `application/ld+json` isn't anywhere near a standard mime type either. Standards are there for a reason.

Comment: `<div class = "six columns">`. This isn't how classes work (unless you want the element to have the classes "six" and "columns"). Run away. Run while you can.

Comment: We are testing AMP on one of our sites.Its not a particular high traffic site so its worth the risk, im just shocked one can write simple JavaScript with out AMP having a hissyfit

Comment: They use `::after` as a clearfix, but I have no idea why they set it to `display: table`

Comment: Yep. They really use a video element on their homepage. Perhaps it's because they can't use javascript to create a simple slideshow because that wouldn't be fast enough?

Comment: I'm confused. At one point they use an `h1` for a header, but later they use `<div class="rows">` to make one, which is also the markup for the next, non-header, row.

Comment: So, what is the actual question here? "How do I bypass the restrictions put on by AMP so that I can build a decent website with it?" Frankly, I'd just download a new static page anytime a menu is clicked. And if the boss wants it animated, reply: "sure. I'll require a video file showing the animation, though."

Comment: "static page anytime a menu is clicked" this is the most likely scenario im gonna have to implement. Its bizarre that AMP supposed to be for fast mobile pages and having to load a static page just to get to the menu feels like it defeats the purpose of using AMP altogether. The reason why we are going the AMP direction is to help with rankings apparently google favors or will be favoring websites with  AMP implemented.So far im not that impressed, with  just a few lines of JavaScript can improve the sites speed drastically when it come to load and AMP seems insistant for this not to happen

Comment: An alternative would be a CSS hack. The idea is that you use a hidden checkbox to track the menu state. Then you can even animate the menu using CSS transitions. If it hurts the SEO ultimately I don't know. But it might as well.

Comment: AMP has JS ... Idk if it's worth looking into but I guess in your unfortunate situation I suppose so... https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/src

Answer (score 2):

Third-party javascript isn't allowed in valid AMP outside of `amp-iframe`. I'd recommend [`amp-sidebar`](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-sidebar/) for a simple hamburger menu.

Answer (score 0):

In August 2019, they launched [`<amp-script>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) to allow custom JavaScript to be added.